# Separate list for each object instance

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am working on creating a Library project. I have a problem with implementing one logic. Let's say I will have 2 library users: user1 and user2. I would like to have a method borrowBook() which will use:

```
ArrayList<Book> borrowedBooks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Everytime user is borrowing book it will be added to a list. The issue is that I know how to make one list for all users using static and it works but I would like to do a separate list for each user. So for example if user1 and user2 will borrow the same book it is fine but if user1 will borrow the same book twice it won't be ok and it will show info: "Give this book first before you borrow it again" or something like this. Any idea how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Map with key as User and value as List of Borrowed Books by that user.

```
Map<User, List<Book>>
```

And Like @Govi S mentioned, you can identify if book is already borrowed by that User.